# Viewport tag not working

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

I am trying to get my site [berlinexpat.url.ph](http://berlinexpat.url.ph) to scale on mobile devices. I have added the code

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

to the head but when I load the site it loads zoomed in instead of showing the whole site on load.

I have tried varios implementation of the viewport tag am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need the Viewport meta with initial scale

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

the website itself will not scale if you use viewport, viewport did what you asked it to do: set the width of the zoom to be equal to the device's width.

thats why the page is zoomed so that the number of pixels the device has is equal to number of pixels displayed
if you want to make the website optimized for mobile devices you need to add a special CSS file that loads if the device is a mobile device

Comment: I have a mobile css stylesheet that is being picked up but it doesn't seem to be resizing/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 320px)
and (max-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */